# Reading CSV - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with some data, I have names in column b and some related information in column A. However not all names have related information

```
    A                   B
 1                      JOHN
 2                      JANE
 3 jane@email.com
 4 phone:0800etcetc 
 5                      ZAIN
 6                      MIKE
 7 email
 8 phon et etc
```

I am trying to write a code that will read column A if there is information in column A I want it to print the name before that in column B and than print the information with that name.

I hope it makes sense. Please let me know if there is a way of doing that.

This is the output i want. I thank you all for help.

```
             A                    B
1           John                   
2           JANE                    jane@email.com
3           JANE                    phone:0800 etc etc
4           ZAIN       
5           MIKE                    email
6           MIKE                    Phone
```

Comment: in the example you posted above, can you show what your expected output would be? Not sure if I'm understanding what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html):

So, something like this:

```
import csv
with open('tmp.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    name = None
    for row in reader:
        if row[1]: 
            name = row[1]
            print(name)
        else:
            print(' '.join([name, row[0]]))
```

output:

```
B
John
JANE
JANE jane@email.com
JANE phone:foo
ZAIN
MIKE
MIKE email
MIKE phone
```

I don't see a way of distinguishing with lookback.

Usually, if you're using Pandas you could use the built in functionality.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
```

Note: its bad practice to read/write csv files directly.  You should use either the csv library (`import csv`) or pandas.  The reason for this is that they handle special characters, escape types, provide delimiter options and all of the edge cases that happen in a production environment over time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
import sys

csvFile = open('pathOfCSV','r')
for line in csvFile.readlines():
    l = line.split()
    if len(l) > 1: # informations in columns A and B
        sys.stdout.write('ColumnA : %s, ColumnB : %s\n'%(l[0],l[1]))
csvFile.close()
```

This work if your csv file is not too big, if not you must use `readline()`function and batch your file.

Comment: Not only shouldn't you readlines on the csv file, but you should just use the print method, not sys.stdout.

Comment: print is the same. I prefere using sys.stdout because it s better for me, sometime I use stdout and sometime stderr, its clearer

Comment: For that purpose you should use logger.info / logger.error .. you can do what you like, but usually the goal is for simplicity.  just another opinion.  usually print isn't used in any application of scale

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you want to do, but you can read your file with this:

```
out_file = open("out_file.csv", "w", encoding="your encoding")
with open("file.csv", "r", encoding="your encoding") as file:
    for line in file:
        cut = line.split("your separator")
        colA = cut[0]
        colB = cut[1]

        # you can output result with:
        output = colA + "\t"   # any separator you want
        output += colB + "\n"
        out_file.write(output)
```

You can do a test on col A inside the `for` and change the output.