# How to iterate through values in csv file

Tags: python, json, linux, csv

Here I am trying to write a simple python script which will iterate through all the values in column and get me the result.

My example.csv file contains values as

> `Name,Client_ID__c,Endpoint_URL__c`

```
SubmitCustomerOrder,<unique_value-1>,https://<base_url>/customerordermanagement/apikey/v1/submitcustomerorder

RetrieveSubscriberEvents,<unique_value-2>,https:<base_url>eventservice/v1/retrieveSubscriberEvents
```

. So when I run a script it should read example.csv file as Endpoint_URL__c + Client_ID__c and then get me a success or failure response code as a output file. eg: output.csv or output.json

I am new to python and tried hard but could not able to get the effective results. Can somebody please help me to achieve this

Comment: If you could show the code you have tried so far, we may be able to provide more guidance.

Comment: Check out the `pandas` module for python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading CSV - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077165/reading-csv-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try csv

```
import csv

csvfile = ' .....  '
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in csv_reader:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSV module as @Mace suggested, only tweak I would make would be use the `DictReader` instead. Like this:

```
import csv

csvfile = 'Path/To/File/'
for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
    print(row)
    name = row.get('Name')
    client_id = row.get('Client_ID__c')
```

That way you can access your columns with `.get()` rather than integer indexes

Or you could use `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas 

df = pd.read_csv('Path/To/File')

name = df.loc['Name']
```

Then you can access your dataframe `df` a number of ways here I have used `loc[col_name]` but you can use `.get(col_name)` or just `df[col_name]`. Please see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html